# User not associated with post model

Tags: django, forms, model

I am trying to get the current logged in user to be the `author` of the post they create from the Post model. So far all of the information they fill out in the form gets collected and successfully stored in the database except for the user. At the moment it shows that there's no user logged in and I'm not sure why that is. I've tried putting the request. user and instance=request.user for the POST and GET requests and so far nothing seems to work.

views.py

```
def create(request):
    form = PostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.user = request.user
        instance.save()
        return render(request, 'classifieds/latest-ads.html')
    else:
        form = PostForm(instance=request.user)
        args = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'classifieds/create-post.html', args)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class Post(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    body = models.TextField()
    contact_email = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True)
    contact_number = models.IntegerField(default=250, null=True)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='ad_pictures', default='')



    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Post
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = (
            'price',
            'title',
            'body',
            'author',
            'contact_email',
            'contact_number',
            'picture',
        )
```

[Here](https://i.gyazo.com/8e7f0f2211d1998aa911288ba386bdce.png) is a picture of the `create-post.html` template rendered as `form.as_p`. Note that the `Author` field is blank. If I select the correct author from the drop down, the post gets saved as it should. I can't get the logged-in user to show up, however.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I just noticed another strange thing in your view at `form = PostForm(instance=request.user)`. `PostForm` is a ModelForm for `Post` model. So, the `instance` argument should be used to edit an already existing `Post` object, not the `User` object. But this might be unrelated to your original issue.

Comment: Ok, I removed it. It didn't change anything but I appreciate the heads up. Thanks

Comment: Can you remove the `'author'` field from `PostForm` fields and try again?

Comment: I've updated the answer, but you've already *accepted* it. I don't know why the foreignkey field must be excluded from the ModelForm. Docs don't mention it. I'll investigate this further and update the answer with proper explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the foreignkey field to User is called `author`. But you're trying to add the user to the post using an unnamed field called `user`.

In the `create` view, at line:

```
...
instance.user = request.user
#        ^^^^ this is your mistake
...
```

You need to use `instance.author = request.user`.

---

**UPDATE:** You also need to exclude the the `author` foreignkey field from your ModelForm.

I don't know the exact reason why the foreignkey field must be excluded, but I'll update the answer if I find one. It may quite possibly be a bug because the docs don't mention anything like this.

Comment: Okay I changed user to author, but unfortunately that didn't change anything. The form still renders with no user selected.